# select columns base on different conditions in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I need help for this code. What did I do wrong. I want a result that give me group by Commercial, Residential and Agriculture basic column amount in current and previous revperiod column. How to accomplish with this code or better any suggestion about it. Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT  (CASE (c.classcode)
         WHEN 'C' THEN 'COMMERCIAL'
         WHEN 'R' THEN 'RESIDENTIAL'
         WHEN 'A' THEN 'AGRICULTURE' END) AS CLASSIFICATION,
        ( SELECT  SUM(a.basic)
            FROM  cashreceiptitem_rpt_online a
            JOIN  cashreceipt_rpt b  ON a.rptreceiptid=b.objid
            JOIN  rptledger c  ON a.rptledgerid=c.objid
            WHERE  b.month='11'
              AND  a.revperiod='current'
        ) AS BC, 
        ( SELECT  SUM(a.basic)
            FROM  cashreceiptitem_rpt_online a
            JOIN  cashreceipt_rpt b  ON a.rptreceiptid=b.objid
            JOIN  rptledger c  ON a.rptledgerid=c.objid
            WHERE  b.month='11'
              AND  a.revperiod='previous'
        ) AS BPC
    FROM  cashreceiptitem_rpt_online a
    JOIN  cashreceipt_rpt b  ON a.rptreceiptid=b.objid
    JOIN  rptledger c  ON a.rptledgerid=c.objid
    WHERE  b.month='11'
```

I have this error `Error Code: 1242; Subquery returns more than 1 row.`

Comment: What is the expected output you are trying to get?

Comment: I believe you need to use a `GROUP BY` to get the sums instead of using subqueries for each type. Let me know if you need help using it.

Comment: I can see the Commercial, Residential, Agriculture basic amount sum up with different revperiod column which is the current and previous. So I name it as BC if current and as BPC if previous revperiod.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show some data and what the expected output will be?

Comment: No avail I try a GROUP BY on the end still have this error Subquery returns more than 1 row. I shows up it only sum up all the basic amount all to a one classcode. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your table structure but you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT c.classcode, SUM(a.basic), SUM(aprev.basic)
FROM cashreceiptitem_rpt_online a
JOIN cashreceiptitem_rpt_online aprev 
    ON a.rptreceiptid = aprev.rptreceiptid
JOIN cashreceipt_rpt b ON a.rptreceiptid=b.objid
JOIN cashreceipt_rpt bprev ON a.rptreceiptid=bprev.objid
JOIN rptledger c ON a.rptledgerid=c.objid
WHERE b.month='11' AND bprev.month='11'
AND a.revperiod='current' AND aprev.revperiod = 'previous'
GROUP BY c.classcode;
```

You'll need to figure out appropriate joins for your table's primary keys.

Comment: I got an Error Code: 1054; Unknown column 'aprev' in 'where clause'

Comment: Edited to fix issue

Comment: can you explain how you do this? ty. i never thought about it that i can join the table 2 times and declared it as a prev..

Comment: Did it work as expected? I am basically joining the concerned tables twice, once to get the value for current year and once to get the value for previous year. Then in the end, use a `GROUP BY` to get the aggregated values.

Comment: Now how can i sum up all the sum(a.basic) as total. To have a total of all of that column.